# how to make pivot more than one column value sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this table

```
     country weeek  quantity 1  quantity 2  quantity 3
0        1    sa        3235         365         123
1        1    su        6698       32135        1234
2        1    mo        1565        5689       12345
```

Desired output:

```
   country  sa_q1  su_q1  mo_q1  sa_q2  su_q2  mo_q2  sa_q3  su_q3  mo_q3
0        1   3235   6698   1565    365  32135   5689    123   1234  12345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select country,
       sum(case when week = 'sa' then quantity1 else 0 end) as sa1,
       sum(case when week = 'su' then quantity1 else 0 end) as su1,
       sum(case when week = 'mo' then quantity1 else 0 end) as mo1,
       sum(case when week = 'sa' then quantity2 else 0 end) as sa2,
       sum(case when week = 'su' then quantity2 else 0 end) as su2,
       sum(case when week = 'mo' then quantity2 else 0 end) as mo2,
       sum(case when week = 'sa' then quantity3 else 0 end) as sa3,
       sum(case when week = 'su' then quantity3 else 0 end) as su3,
       sum(case when week = 'mo' then quantity3 else 0 end) as mo3
from t
group by country;
```